# Sharepoint 2013 Auto Create Managed Property not work

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, managed-property, crawl

Hi i developed a site column, custom content type and a list definition.
I set the value for this column and started crawling but i don't find these properties in search schema.
If i add this column manually in a library and start crawling, these properties are showed.
What 's the difference?

Answer (score 2):

I think it should work as you described - the following steps are needed, maybe you can try again:

> To be picked up, the new items must be crawled. If you’re not using
>   Continuous crawling, this will be limited to when your incremental
>   crawls run.
>
> The column must be a site column!
>
> To be picked up, crawled
>   properties MUST have a value.
>
> To be applied to items already existing
>   in the index, a full crawl will be required still.
>
> http://www.myfatblog.co.uk/index.php/2012/12/automagic-managed-properties-in-sharepoint-2013-search/

Or Technet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613136.aspx

Btw, I would not recommend you the automatically approach, you loose a lot IMHO. The managed property benefits a lot when you merge several crawled properties into one managed property.

Comment: +1 For the column must be a site column

Answer (score 0):

The difference between setting the column as index-able at the list level will mean that all other lists that have this column will not be indexed.

To expand on Max's list I also recommend:

- Index reset

I have seen scenarios where following the steps Max outlined ends in the crawled property still not being created. I recommend manually creating the properties.

You can create the managed property and crawled property in the search administration page or via powershell script using the following commands:

```
$crawledproperty = New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCrawledProperty -SearchApplication [search app] -Category [Category] -PropSet [Property set] -Name [Name] -IsNameEnum $false -VariantType [crawled property template varient type]

$managedproperty = New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty -Name [ManagedPropertyName] -SearchApplication [searchapp] -Type [property type] -FullTextQueriable [$true or $false] -Queryable $true -Retrievable $true -EnabledForScoping $true -NameNormalized $false -Safe $true -NoWordBreaker [$true or $false] -Description [Description] -Refinable [$true or $false] -sortable [$true or $false] -HasMultipleValues [$true or $false]
```

For more information see here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/new-spenterprisesearchmetadatacrawledproperty?view=sharepoint-ps