# How to get a crawled property? SP2010

Tags: 2010, search, crawled-property

I have a site column added through a custom feature. The column is a text Column of the type "**Multiple Lines of Text**". It already contains values, but I can't find the crawled Property to map it as a managed Property. I am sure I have not reached the boundaries of 500.000 crawled Properties and I don't know why the other Columns of the feature which I added 1:1 similar to the Column I can't find are findable and the one is not.
I have also made 2 Index Reset's since the Content is published and several Full Crawls.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787%28v=office.14%29.aspx

[Sharepoint 2013 Auto Create Managed Property not work](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/68683/sharepoint-2013-auto-create-managed-property-not-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New custom server columns won't show up as crawled properties until you've populated that column with data and a search has crawled it. So for instance, you create a new list and use your new server columns in that list. You must create a new item in the list and you must populate each new server column field with data (no nulls) and then run a crawl.

Comment: Yea you are right. My farm admin didn't do all the steps I orderd him to do. So it wasn't realy complete and I absurdly wonderd why the property was not crawled. But thanks for your answer